# Out of memory exception caused by FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to load an image and performing some process on it each time when an new image was create in a folder. The code ran fine in the debugging mode. However, when I copied the executable folder to the target machine. The FileSystemWatcher threw out an exception of "out of memory" every time. The .jpg is only 60KB. The code is written in C#.

Could anyone help me on this? Thank you.

```
private void fileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       source = new Image<Gray, byte>((Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(e.FullPath));
       frame = source.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(180), new Gray(255));
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("File Loading Failed: " + ex.Message);
   }
}
```

A stack trace is here:

.ctor at offset 342 in file:line:column :0:0

Main at offset 59 in file:line:column :0:0

Comment: Can you please include a stack trace?

Comment: I doubt that `FileSystemWatcher` would cause an out of memory exception all by itself. Creating a massive number of bitmaps and not disposing them properly could though.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie, a stack trace is added here

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy, I understand what you said. However, the exception is threw out even when the folder had just 1 image.

Comment: Surely you have more detail in your stack trace than that - is that all you see in `ex.StackTrace`? Also, if you run your try-catch block _without_ the file system watcher, do you still get an exception? I don't believe this exception is being caused by the `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: That stack trace reads more like poetry than actual stack trace. You should post the actual dump. Also: are you giving your `FileSystemWatcher` a specific directory path to monitor? Not setting the filter properly could cause it to hammer the `Created` event (ultimately leading to gazillions of images being constructed). Set a breakpoint inside your event handler, see how often it gets hit.

Comment: What is source and frame? If they are members in the sourounding class, then they will be overriden by each call of fileSystemWatcher_Created and the bitmap is left in memory. So, the question may be, how often is it called? Can you put in a kind of debug message?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie, the newly updated stack trace is here. That's all I have in the stack trace.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy, yes, a proper folder path is given to the code. Everything runs fine on my computer, debugging mode or run time. I only saw this exception on the target machine.

Comment: @DieterMeemken, source is the defined as an Image<Gray, byte> and it is a global variable. frame is just the binarized format of the source. They will be called about once every 40 seconds since the new image is generated to the folder at that frequency.

Comment: That exception is not thrown by FSW, hard to see why think it is.  The Image class is very good at throwing it.  Bitmaps takes lots and lots of unmanaged memory.  .NET programmers ignore the Dispose() method a lot, nothing like Image to remind them that it isn't really optional.

Comment: Is it possible that you're compiling for AnyCPU and debugging on x64 but deploying to a 32-bit machine?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie, the target machine is also a x64 machine.

Comment: So how much memory is the process using when it dies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're replacing your `source` `Bitmap` instance on each call to `fileSystemWatcher_Created` without disposing of the previous instance. `Bitmap` objects are wrappers around unmanaged GDI+ resources, and must be [explicitly disposed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8th8381z.aspx) when you're no longer using them. The same will apply to your `frame` object. The code below adds explicit disposal to your event handler. Note that I'm locking to avoid threading problems.

```
try
{
    lock (fileSystemWatcher)
    {
        var oldSource = source;
        var oldFrame = frame;

        source = new Image<Gray, byte>((Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(e.FullPath));
        frame = source.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(180), new Gray(255));

        if (oldSource != null)
            oldSource.Dispose();

        if (oldFrame != null)
            oldFrame.Dispose();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("File Loading Failed: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: This didn't solve the problem. Exceptions still exist.

Comment: Are you creating other `System.Drawing` objects elsewhere in your code? These will need to be disposed also.

Comment: Otherwise, if the images you're working with are of particularly large dimensions, you may want to try disposing of the old ones _before_ instantiating the new ones.

Comment: The image is a jpg file with size about 20 KB and resolution of 640 by 480 pixels.

Comment: I found there is another image instance that was not disposed properly. Finally, made it work.